# How do I reference a template from a class method in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

Is it possible to reference a template from a class method in Django? Let's say I have the following class in my models (for an offline speaker series):

```
class Event(models.Model): 
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    desc = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    location = models.ForeignKey('Location', blank=True, null=True)
    speaker = models.ForeignKey('Speaker', blank=True, null=True)
```

And I want to use these attributes to populate a template and use the resulting string of HTML in an API post. How do I reference the HTML template from a class method like this:

```
def create_event_html(self):
    # This is not working with or without Quotes        
    t = Template(templates/event_template.html) 

    c = Context(self)
    return t.render(c)
```

I want to call this class method on save given a certain condition, but I don't think that's relevant here...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Template(templates/event_template.html)` would never work, because that simply isn't valid Python - it's trying to divide the (non-existent) value 'templates' by the 'html' attribute of the (also non-existent) object 'event_template'. If that's not clear to you, you should do an introductory Python tutorial.

`Template('templates/event_template.html')` is valid Python, but will be looking in the wrong place for the template file: the template loaders already look under 'templates', so that will be looking in 'templates/templates/' for the 'event_template.html' file. Remove the directory reference.

Once that's done, you'll have another problem in that `Context` expects a dictionary, and you are passing `self`. Unless you have overridden `__getitem__` on your model class, this will not work. You should probably just pass a dictionary with one entry, eg `{'item': self}`, and in your template you can reference the various attributes of `item`.

Comment: Thanks, @DanielRoseman - I just dropped the path without quotes in as an example. Maybe where I'm getting confused is that t = Template('event_template.html') doesn't work from the project shell. It just interprets the template name as a string and returns it - is that simply because the template directories variable in settings.py isn't constructed unless you runserver?

Comment: Sorry, I realize that I am wrong above. As you say, `Template('whatever')` constructs a template from a string. You need to use `get_template(location)` from `django.template.loader`, as documented [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/templates/api/#django.template.loader.get_template). But probably much easier overall to use [`render_to_string`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/templates/api/#the-render-to-string-shortcut).

Comment: Ahh, perfect. Confirmed that render_to_string does exactly as I need. Thanks again!